# product images missing after installing extension

Tags: magento2, static-content

When I am installing some extension in Magento 2 using PHP `bin/magento` then after doing that then my [site](http://www.atmcteknik-test.dk/) has a problem which is the all the images including product and everything appears to be missing. This problem doesn't happen before. So I started uninstalling the extension in the hope that it will return back to normal. unfortunately, it didn't

so are there any advice on how to restore all my missing images back in Magento 2? I install the image using sample data.

Update: Below is the screenshot of the error using F12.

Why is all the image nonexistent after I do an upgrade?

[image]

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you run the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command after install the extension?

Comment: yes I did it numerous times. but how come all the images is not loading? this what bugs me the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run these commands on the **root** of your Magento install to fix many commons problems (like yours) related to folder permissions, deployed files, cache and etc:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
composer install && composer update -vv;
php -r "opcache_reset();"
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy;
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Comment: yes, your method works very well. thanks.

Comment: wow, that's work! you save my day

Answer (score 1):

This issue is similar with [this issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9275) after upgrading to Magento 2.1.6. I have solved this issue by firing `bin/magento catalog:images:resize` command via console/terminal.

Comment: I already did that but the image is still missing. do you have any other solution?

Comment: Can you give screenshot of your web console log while loading the page? Just press `F12` if you use Chrome.

Comment: there I had added the screenshot. and it seems to be error404notfound.

Comment: *Very long process (~30 mins) and didn't help*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem that my images were missing after security upgrade from 2.2.2 to 2.2.3.

My problem was, that after shop upgrade my .htaccess was set back in original and it has the option "Option ExecCGI".
If you remove this option from the .htaccess in /magento/pub/ it may can help, that magento can load the images in /pub/media/ again.

Greets Loqic

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.2.4, I had to remove the "Option ExecCGI" line from the .htaccess located here: */pub/media/*